# The provided share path is longer than Windows Backup can support

Tags: windows, backup, system-restore, wbadmin

Previously I made a backup

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\ftpback-rbxx-xxx.xxx.net\nsxxxxxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xx.eu\C\20191210_071757 -allCritical -systemState -quiet
```

Trying to restore

```
wbadmin start systemstaterecovery -version:12/10/2019-15:18 -backupTarget:\\ftpback-rbxx-xxx.xxx.net\nsxxxxxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xx.eu\C\20191210_071757 -quiet -autoReboot
```

I get the following error

> The provided share path is longer than Windows Backup can support. The maximum network path supported is 110 characters.

I cannot short the network shared folder because is provided by third hosting. There is any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shorten the path I would create a dummy DNS entry, like d.com and make it resolve to ftpback-rbxx-xxx.xxx.net.

Your entry would look like;

```
wbadmin start systemstaterecovery -version:12/10/2019-15:18 -backupTarget:\\d.com\nsxxxxxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xx.eu\C\20191210_071757 -quiet -autoReboot
```

Else I would copy the folder locally to use it from inside your LAN on another share with a shorter path inside it.

Comment: Nice suggestion! Another way (I ended with this one) is to ping ftpback-rbxx-xxx.xxx.net and rename 20191210_071757 to "_" to use -backupTarget:\\1.2.3.4\nsxxxxxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xx.eu\C\\_